# How can I check whether a file exists before downloading it from an FTP server?

Tags: ruby, ftp

How can I check whether a file exists in my local directory before downloading it from an FTP server.
when i download the file for the first time i am keeping mtime as my file name.

```
 file = "03-12-15 05:46PM 69925 XXX.jpg" #file from ftp

 local_file_name = file.split().join("_") #03-12-15_05:46PM_69925_XXX.jpg
 check_file = File.exist?("path/to/folder/local_file_name")
    if !check_file
        ftp.getbinaryfile("03-12-15_05:46PM_69925_XXX.jpg", "path/to/folder/local_file_name")
    end
```

Comment: File.exists?(file_name)

Comment: i tried this but it downloads the file next time :(

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't need to download if the file exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
File.exist?("/path/to/the/file")
```

Here is a [link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-exist-3F) to documentation.

Good luck!

**UPDATE - suggestion**

Could you confirm that your script looks like this (please, read carefully as I changed it slightly):

```
file = "03-12-15 05:46PM 69925 XXX.jpg" #file from ftp

local_file_name = file.split().join("_") #03-12-15_05:46PM_69925_XXX.jpg
check_file = File.exist?("path/to/folder/#{local_file_name}")
if !check_file
  ftp.getbinaryfile("03-12-15_05:46PM_69925_XXX.jpg", "path/to/folder/#{local_file_name}")
end
```

Comment: `File.exists?` is deprecated now, use `File.exist?` instead.

Comment: i tried the file still downloads next time when i connect to ftp :(

Comment: Hey @Stefan! Thank you for pointing that out! Slightly different when typing, but huge impact in stability!

Comment: Could you show more of your code then @Ranjith? It's difficult to address the problem with the brief description provided

Comment: @Ranjith - there might be couple things. Please, read through the code I put in my update to the answer, and compare it with what you have. Maybe there is an issue wit preparing the full file path, and thus the script can't find the file?